# generating tuples using n-lists with itertools.product

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-itertools, cartesian-product

How can I use [itertools.product](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) function if I don't know the number of the lists? I have list and it has lists inside of it.

Like,

```
lis = [[1,2,3],[6,7,8],[2,4,5]]
```

Normally I need to do,

```
product([1,2,3],[6,7,8],[2,4,5])
```

How do I do that if the input is a list like in the example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:
`product(*lis)`
It's called [argument unpacking](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).
Short note: you can use argument unpacking with named parameters also, with double star:

```
def simpleSum(a=1,b=2):
    return a + b
simpleSum(**{'a':1,'b':2}) # returns 3
```

Comment: I did not know that. I will certainly check it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @genclik27 you're welcome. you can use it with named parameters also, check out my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use [argument unpacking](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```
>>> lis = [[1,2,3],[6,7,8],[2,4,5]]
>>> list(itertools.product(*lis))
[(1, 6, 2), (1, 6, 4), (1, 6, 5), (1, 7, 2), (1, 7, 4), (1, 7, 5), (1, 8, 2),
 (1, 8, 4), (1, 8, 5), (2, 6, 2), (2, 6, 4), (2, 6, 5), (2, 7, 2), (2, 7, 4),
 (2, 7, 5), (2, 8, 2), (2, 8, 4), (2, 8, 5), (3, 6, 2), (3, 6, 4), (3, 6, 5),
 (3, 7, 2), (3, 7, 4), (3, 7, 5), (3, 8, 2), (3, 8, 4), (3, 8, 5)]
>>>
```

Comment: Very simple. Thanks, this is what I was looking for.